# Capturing items from comma delimited csv with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture the `starttime`, `stoptime`, `tripduration`, `from_station_id`, `to_station_id`, `gender`, `birthyear` from the following data.

```
trip_id,starttime,stoptime,bikeid,tripduration,from_station_name,to_station_name,from_station_id,to_station_id,usertype,gender,birthyear
431,10/13/2014 10:31,10/13/2014 10:48,SEA00298,985.935,2nd Ave & Spring St,Occidental Park / Occidental Ave S & S Washington St,CBD-06,PS-04,Member,Male,1960
```

I just want to be able to have the regex identify these items from the code.

Comment: If you are using `csv` there is no need for regex to solve this problem as the data is comma separated.

Comment: What is the source of the data? Is it in a file, a string, or what?

Comment: It is in a .csv file. I have to only select those values and extract those values from each of the rows that meet the conditions that were given.

Comment: The [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the standard library is the best way to read CSV files.

Comment: It must be written using regex, its a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really really want a regex then you can use the following one:

```
([^,]*)(?=,|$)
```

**TESTED:**

[image]

Good luck and let me know if you need some explanations.